# Dynamically include all classes inheriting from MyBaseClass from a folder

Tags: php

I'm in need of some help.

I have a folder containing classes: /my/folder

I have a class file /my/otherfolder/MyBaseClass.php containing a corresponding class.

I would like to dynamically (in the sense that I do not hard code any class names inside /my/folder) load all classes in /my/folder and for the ones inheriting from MyBaseClass I would like to call the base method myBase().

I'm looking for the cleanest, easiest way. Performance is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

A very old example from code I wrote long ago... the require_once works because all the classes involved were in the same directory, which was added manually to the path.

```
function __autoload($class_name)
{
    require_once("{$class_name}.php");
}
```

However, apparently that function has been superseded:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php